# Read and error check a CSV file in objective c

Tags: objective-c, csv

I have this code for reading the file in:

```
NSString *sourceFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"csv"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Where do i need to store the .csv file in order to to able to read and also how do i error check if xcode can not read the file?

I'm pretty new to objective c.

Comment: i meant csv sorry, error corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to get the file path for you so the file needs to be copied into the bundle during the build. See the build phases in your project.

Xcode doesn't specifically work with CSV files so you can't check if it can read it.

CSV files are just text, the most you could check really is that each line of text had the correct number of commas...

Also, when an SDK method has an `error` parameter you should use it, at least to log the error details if one is passed back to you. Otherwise you're flying blind even for simple errors.